# window.location.reload() used in my js page I am getting logout I am using spring security

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-security

I need to reload my page using window.location.reload() but I am facing logout.
I am using spring security jquery

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not maintaining the current logged in user session. Use SecurityContextHolder in spring to get the principal user and return the current logged in user object to maintain the session. This will even work if you implement window.location.reload(). Kindly go through looking into the concept of SecurityContextHolder in spring to get the principal user.